# set a cookie to test a helper

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I'm trying to test my helper function which returns a string set in a cookie. The test looks like this:

```
context 'if the cookie does exist' do
  it 'returns filled hash' do
    request.cookies['history'] = '{\"1_2_2\":\"HAI\"}'
    expect(history_terms_array).to eq('{\"1_2_2\":\"HAI\"}')
  end
end
```

However for some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: request.cookies['history'] = 'abc'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `cookies' for nil:NilClass
```

am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the request object is even available, instead of doing that, try using a stub

```
allow(request).to receive(:[]).with('history').and_return('{\"1_2_2\":\"HAI\"}')
expect(history_terms_array).to eq('{\"1_2_2\":\"HAI\"}')
```